# Data retrieval from Orion Context Broker subscription fails

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

With a successful subscription in Orion Context Broker, a listening accumulator server fails to recieve any data, under any circumstances I can find to test.

We are using an Ubuntu virtual machine that has a nested virtual machine with FIWARE Orion in it. Having subscribed to Orion Context Broker and confirmed that it was successful by checking the database and also having confirmed that data is successfully updated, the accumulator server fails to respond.  unable to tell if this is a failure to send from Orion, or to receive by accumulator, and unsure how to check and continue, we humbly beg the wisdom of the stack overflow community.

We have run the accumulator server on both virtual machine on the same PC and on another PC with non-vm Ubuntu. The script we are using to subscribe is presented below:

[Orion VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdeSR.png)

```
{
"duration": "P1M",
"entities": [
{
"type": "Thing",
"id": "Sensor_GV_01",
"isPattern": "false"
}
],
"throttling": "PT1S",
"reference": "http://10.224.24.236:1028/accumulate",
"attributes": [
"temperature",
"pressure"
]
}
```

EDIT 1

upon using GET/v2/subscriptions/ we receive that the subscription is present but it gives only basic info, no Timesent values. It is pretty much the same thing we receive when we ask MongoDB directly.
Also, forgot to mention, Orion version we are using is 1.9.0 [Subscription check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3plL.png)

Comment: Have you checked connection from the place where Orion runs to the accumulator? For instance, running `telnet 10.224.24.236 1028` in the same place Orion is running.

Comment: Orion notifies each time you update the entity and there is a matching subscription. Which request (verb + url + headers + payload) are you using to update?

Comment: What about the inforamtion gathered in the subscription itself? Use `GET /v2/subscriptions/<subId>` in order to check `timesSent` value and `lastNotificaiton/lastFailure/lastSuccess` timestamps.

Comment: Please edit your question post in order to include the information requested in the above questions in order to help you to trace the cause of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: What is your "error message"? I think the problem is the "port forwarding" in your VM. You need to configure it in order to access external IPs. Try `ping 10.224.24.236` from your VM that is running Orion. If ping fails, this is a connection problem, as suggested by @fgalan , and you will probably need to setup your VM port forwarding...

Comment: question was edited